# Horizontal Scrolling with Vertical Navbar - Content under Navbar when scrolling back

Tags: html, css, padding, navbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have made a Horizontal Scrolling webpage.
But i have a problem with my navbar which is vertically.

When I am on the Home-Screen and then go to another view, everything seems to be perfect, but when I go back, for example from "kontakt" to "über mich" the content is under the navbar.

I have tried to put in a `margin-right: -60px;` and a `padding-right: -60px;` But that isn't working.

You can watch the project on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/615b216e/1/

Is there a way to get these Pages in the right position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your navigation. You have a navigation ID outside you're navigation class. I put them together in the div.

https://jsfiddle.net/615b216e/3/

```
<div class="nav" id="navigation">
```

Hope this helps you